# Set "expires" header for a whole directory

Tags: .htaccess

So let's say:

```
- .htaccess
* assets
 |> images
   |> logo.png
 |> css
   |> style.css
   |> home.css
```

How can i set the expires header for the whole assets folder and its contents?

I know that i can set it by type like:

```
ExpiresByType text/javascript "modification plus 2 hours 45 minutes"
```

But what about for a whole directory?

Comment: This is not meant as an RTFM rant - it's a fair question - but the solution is easy to find in the documentation. 1. Look up [`ExpiresByType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype) 2. Look what else is there 3. End up with [`ExpiresDefault`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresdefault)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the .conf level, use a `<directory>` directive:

```
<Directory  /path/to/your/assets/folder>
    ExpiresDefault ...
</Directory>
```

If you have only .htaccess control, then put a .htaccess into the assets folder with the same [`ExpiresDefault`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresdefault) directive